# Index of the item that is clicked in ListView

Tags: android

Android:
Hello, i am trying to get index of the item that is clicked but i don't know how i can do it.
I want if i click on any item in listview it will open SmsManager with number of this item(Phone Number).
Can somebody tell me how i can do it?

There is source code:

```
 list1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position,
                    long id) {
                SmsManager m = SmsManager.getDefault();
                Uri uriSMSURIs = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
                Cursor cc = getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURIs, null, null, null, null);
                String phoneNumber  = cc.getString(cc.getColumnIndex("address"));
                m.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber , null, phoneNumber , null, null);


            }

        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement

> onListItemClick

```
    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, final int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);  

Log.i("the Item clicked is :: ",  position);

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The "index of the item witch [sic] is clicked" is the `position` parameter supplied to `onItemClick()`.